# Window receives infinite amount of messages when mouse is hooked

Tags: delphi, hook, message

I am writing an application which should draw a circle in place where user clicks a mouse. To achieve that i am hooking the mouse globally using `SetWindowHookEx(WH_MOUSE,...)`

The hooking, and the procedure that processes mouse action is in DLL. The procedure posts a registered message when it finds that mouse button was clicked using `PostMessage(FindWindow('TMyWindow',nil), MyMessage, 0,0);`

My application with TMyWindow form processes the messages in `WndProc` procedure.  I check whether the message that came is the same as my registered one and only then draw the circle. After drawing the circle i create a timer, which should free the image after 500ms.

So everything seems to work just fine until i actually click on any part of my application form (for example click on still existing circle that was drawn not long ago). When i do that, form starts receiving my registered messages infinitely ans of course circle drawing procedure gets called every time.

I dont understand why is it doing so. Why is it working fine when i click somewhere off my application form but hangs when i click inside my form?

Let me know if you need more details.

Thanks

**EDIT 1**:

Main unit. $202 message is WM_LBUTTONUP.

```
unit main;

interface

uses
    HookCommon,
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls, Menus, AppEvnts;


type
    TTimer2 = class(TTimer)
    private
        FShape: TShape;
    public
        destructor Destroy; override;
        property Shape: TShape read FShape write FShape;
    end;

type
  TShowMouseClick = class(TForm)
    timerCountTimer: TTimer;
    tray: TTrayIcon;
    popMenu: TPopupMenu;
    mnuExit: TMenuItem;
    mnuActive: TMenuItem;
    N1: TMenuItem;
    mnuSettings: TMenuItem;
    timersStx: TStaticText;
    procedure timerCountTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure mnuExitClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    timerList: TList;
    procedure shape();
    procedure freeInactive(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_USER + 1545;
  public
    shapeColor: Tcolor;                    
    procedure TimerExecute(Sender: TObject);
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  ShowMouseClick: TShowMouseClick;



implementation
{$R *.dfm}

uses settings;

{$REGION 'Hide from TaskBar'}
procedure TShowMouseClick.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowWindow(Application.Handle, SW_HIDE);  
end;
procedure TShowMouseClick.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowWindow(Application.Handle, SW_HIDE);
end;
{$ENDREGION}

procedure TShowMouseClick.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
    inherited WndProc(Message);
    if (Message.Msg = HookCommon.MouseHookMessage) and
        (Message.WParam = $202) then
        shape;
end;

procedure TShowMouseClick.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  BorderStyle := bsNone;
  FormStyle := fsStayOnTop;
  WindowState := wsMaximized;

  mnuActive.Checked := true;
  HookCommon.HookMouse;
  timerList := TList.Create;
  timerList.Clear;
  shapeColor := clGreen;
end;

procedure TShowMouseClick.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
    HookCommon.UnHookMouse;
end;

procedure TShowMouseClick.mnuExitClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Close;
end;

procedure TShowMouseClick.timerCountTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  timersStx.Caption := 'Active timers: ' + IntToStr(timerList.Count);
end;

procedure TShowMouseClick.shape;  
var
  tm: TTimer2;
begin
  tm := TTimer2.Create(nil);

  tm.Tag := 0 ;
  tm.Interval := 1;
  tm.OnTimer := TimerExecute;
  tm.Shape := nil;
  timerList.Add(tm);
  timersStx.Caption := 'Active timers: ' + IntToStr(timerList.Count);
  tm.Enabled := true;
end;

procedure TShowMouseClick.TimerExecute(Sender: TObject);
var
    img: TShape;
    snd: TTimer2;
begin
    snd := nil;
    if Sender is TTimer2 then
        snd := TTimer2(Sender);

    if snd = nil then Exit;

    if snd.Tag = 0 then
    begin
        snd.Interval := 500;
        img := TShape.Create(nil);
        img.Parent := ShowMouseClick;
        img.Brush.Color := clGreen;
        img.Shape := stCircle;
        img.Width := 9;
        img.Height := 9;
        img.Left := Mouse.CursorPos.X-4;
        img.Top := Mouse.CursorPos.Y-3;
        snd.Tag := 1;
        snd.Shape := img;
    end else begin
        snd.Enabled := false;
        PostMessage(ShowMouseClick.Handle,WM_USER + 1545 , 0,0);
        Application.ProcessMessages;
    end;

end;

procedure TShowMouseClick.freeInactive(var Msg: TMessage);
var
    i: integer;
begin
    for i := timerList.Count - 1 downto 0 do
        if TTimer2(timerList[i]).Enabled = false then
        begin
            TTimer2(timerList[i]).Free;
            timerList.Delete(i);
        end;
end;

destructor TTimer2.Destroy;
begin
    FreeAndNil(FShape);
    inherited;
end;

end.
```

Common unit.

```
unit HookCommon;

interface

uses Windows;

var
  MouseHookMessage: Cardinal;

procedure HookMouse;
procedure UnHookMouse;

implementation

procedure HookMouse; external 'MouseHook.DLL';
procedure UnHookMouse; external 'MouseHook.DLL';

initialization
  MouseHookMessage := RegisterWindowMessage('MouseHookMessage');
end.
```

DLL code.

```
library MouseHook;

uses
  Forms,
  Windows,
  Messages,
  HookCommon in 'HookCommon.pas';

{$J+}
const
  Hook: HHook = 0;
{$J-}


{$R *.res}

function HookProc(nCode: Integer; MsgID: WParam; Data: LParam): LResult; stdcall;
var
  notifyTestForm : boolean;
begin

  notifyTestForm := false;

  if msgID = $202 then
    notifyTestForm := true;
  if notifyTestForm then
  begin
       PostMessage(FindWindow('TShowMouseClick', nil), MouseHookMessage, MsgID, 0);
  end;

  Result := CallNextHookEx(Hook,nCode,MsgID,Data);
end;

procedure HookMouse; stdcall;
begin
  if Hook = 0 then Hook:=SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE,@HookProc,HInstance,0);
end;

procedure UnHookMouse; stdcall;
begin
  UnhookWindowsHookEx(Hook);
  Hook:=0;
end;

exports
  HookMouse, UnHookMouse;

begin
end.
```

The source of the mouse hook stuff is [this](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/mousehook.htm)

Comment: Looks like a recursion, your MouseProc does anything other than posting the registered message?

Comment: Please show your actual code, both for the DLL hook and the MyMessage handler in the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is it working fine when i click somewhere off my application form
>   but hangs when i click inside my form?

You're not posting the message to other windows when you click on them. First you should ask yourself, "what happens if I posted a message in my hook callback to all windows which are posted a `WM_LBUTTONUP`?".

Replace this line

```
PostMessage(FindWindow('TShowMouseClick', nil), MouseHookMessage, MsgID, 0);
```

in your dll code, with this:

```
PostMessage(PMouseHookStruct(Data).hwnd, MouseHookMessage, MsgID, 0);
```

It doesn't matter if the other applications would know or not what MouseHookMessage is, they will ignore the message. Launch your application and click the mouse wildly to other windows. Generally nothing will happen. Unless you click in the client area of *any* Delphi application. You'll instantly freeze it.

The answer to this question lies in both how a VCL message loop runs and how a `WH_MOUSE` hook works. A quote from `MouseProc` callback function's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> [..] The system calls this function whenever an application calls the
>   *GetMessage* or *PeekMessage* function and there is a mouse message to be
>   processed.

Suppose you launch your application and the mouse is hooked, then you hover the mouse on your form and wait till your application calls 'WaitMessage', that it is idle. Now click in the client area to generate mouse messages. What happens is that the OS places messages to your application's main thread's message queue. And what your application does is that to remove and dispatch these messages with `PeekMessage`. This is where applications differ. The VCL first calls 'PeekMessage' with 'PM_NOREMOVE' passed in 'wRemoveMsg' parameter, while most other applications either removes the message with a call to 'PeekMessage' or do the same by using 'GetMessage'.

Now suppose it is 'WM_LBUTTONUP's turn. Refer to the quote above. As soon as `PeekMessage` is called, the OS calls the `MouseProc` callback. The call happens from 'user32.dll', that is, when your hook callback is called the statement following the 'PeekMessage' is not executed yet. Also, remember the VCL loop, the message is still in the queue, it has not been removed. Now, your callback function posts a message to the same message queue and returns. Execution returns to the VCL message loop and VCL again calls 'PeekMessage', this time to remove and dispatch the message, but instead of removing the 'WM_LBUTTONUP', it removes the custom message that you posted. 'WM_LBUTTONUP' remains in the queue. After the custom message is dispatched, since 'WM_LBUTTONUP' is still in the queue, 'PeekMessage' is again called, and again the OS calls the callback so that the callback can post another custom message to be removed instead of the mouse message. This loop effectively freezes the application.

To resolve, either post your message to a different thread that has its own message loop which would in some way synchronize with the main thread, or, I would not especially advice it but, instead of posting the message, *send* it. As an alternative you can remove the 'WM_LBUTTONUP' message yourself from the queue if one exists:

```
procedure TShowMouseClick.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
    inherited WndProc(Message);
    if (Message.Msg = HookCommon.MouseHookMessage) and
        (Message.WParam = $202) then begin
      if PeekMessage(Msg, Handle, WM_LBUTTONUP, WM_LBUTTONUP, PM_REMOVE) then
        DispatchMessage(Msg);  // or eat if you don't need it.

     ..

end;
```

The disadvantage to this approach is that, the PeekMessage itself, as mentioned above, will cause another custom message to be posted, so you'll be receiving those in pairs.

Comment: Thank you, this all makes sense and i tried thinking what could be done. In the DLL i have added the check of whether the `Findwindow()` returned handle is the same as the `PMouseHookStruct` has, at first it seemed to work, i rapidly clicked on the drawn circles and application continued to run. But then i decided to click on the static text that shows active timer count. It froze. Meaning that static text has its own window handle which is not equal to main form. Back to the drawing board

Comment: You're welcome. You can use a label instead of a static, or test if the struct window is a child window and a static, and if it is compare its parent with the FindWindow window. Or try one of the suggestions in the answer..

Comment: Sending instead of posting a message seems to have solved the issue. Now clicking the static text it doesn't hang. I will definitely need to read more about posting and sending messages and what effects can it cause. It may be a good solution in my case but it is interesting to know what would happen in different situations. So far i know that posting a message doesnt wait for response, while sending it - waits.

Comment: @user - Correct, what this means is that you want to return really quick, otherwise whole system might feel unresponsive, even the OS might kick your hook out of the hook chain.

Answer (score 2):

Either your Mouse click or your MyMessage messages are not removed from the Message Queue (unlikely) or they are somehow echoed back, or your code loops in a recursion.

I would try to remove any code from your TMyWindow.WndProc and replace it with some innocuous code (like an OutputDebugString to see it called in the message area of the IDE) to see if it is still looping or not.
Something like:

```
  with Message do
    case Msg of
      WM_MyMessage: OutputDebugString('MyMessage received. Drawing a circle');
    else 
      inherited WndProc(Message);
```

If it's only writing once per click, then the recursion is in your handling of the message (or in the timer handler) to draw/erase the circle.

If it's looping, then your click generates multiple messages or 1 that is spinning forever...

**Update:**
After giving a look at your code, I'd change the way you deal with the timers.
- Don't create the timer with an interval of 1 for the purpose of creating the shape. You'll be flooding your app with Timer events.
- As soon as you enter the Execute, disable the timer
- Avoid calling Application.ProcessMessages.
- You may have some reasons, but I find this very convoluted when it seems to me that a simple OnMouse event on your form could achieve this easily.

Comment: @speedy downvoter: care to enlighten me on what is worthy of a downvote so that I can benefit from your wisdom?

Comment: You've got a good idea. But note my answer, which started as a down vote explanation. Namely, this is a complex system. Seeing what happens with a debugger is a much better solution than printing test output, which can fall into [experimenter's bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experimenter's_bias). There's an example in the article I linked in my answer.

Comment: @Spencer. Read again my answer. I'm not advocating adding printing test output BUT removing half of the possible problem code and testing the framework (i.e. mouse hook click/messaging). Divide and conquer. Also OutputDebugString is far less obtrusive than putting breakpoints when Windows messages are involved.

Comment: I'd dispute you on the output bit. You say he should replace his existing code with an output message. I'd argue he should put a break point at the beginning of the function, which will have the same effect (stopping the program with a notice), but be more powerful. It will also not *change* what he is trying to observe. I don't understand your comment on Windows messages either, since you don't have to step into code with the debugger.

Comment: @Spencer. Also, you probably have never seen/attended any of my sessions about debugging in Delphi. You know that I generally recommend using all kind of advanced breakpoints over adding any ShowMessage/Printing. But in this case, with the sparse information we have, we need first to have an idea of where to look. In the DLL, in the MyMessage handler, in the hooks? that's why validating the DLL/Mouse hook/Messaging without adding code to handle it is IMO a good step.

Comment: It's obvious that this is a debatable issue on proper debugging technique. I do not agree with you about the debugger, but that is not relevant. So if you put a minor edit on the question to allow for voting again, I will change my vote. Edit: just saw your response, and that answers my objections. I'll happily give you a +1 for this.

Comment: @Spencer. If you don't like the output bit, just replace the code there by some NOP. The idea is to see if without THAT code it still loops or not.

Comment: @Spencer. The debugger (even without breaking) involves adding a lot of stuff to the execution (switching context) which in some cases make problems much harder to pinpoint in the debugger compared to using external tools like AQTime. Especially when Windows Messages are involved. I guess it is not really the main point here in this case but...

Comment: I have added the source code. I have breakpointed the wndproc, and it gets into the infinite loop. Receives my message, then receives like 3-4 other messages i didnt try to decode the meanings of, then it received my message again and everything repeats.

Comment: Hi again, the simple mouse event is what i thought would work at first, until i found my form does not receive mouse messages unless i actually click on the form, which hardly ever happens as the whole form is OnTop and has transparency ON. This means it is 'invisible' and i can click through it. Mouse hook solves this problem and the shapes that i draw become visible as they are different color then the transparency one.

Comment: Ah. I see that you're trying to shoot holes in the screen. As Sertac pointed at, the main problem is the DLL PostMessage. I would also clean the code a bit...

Answer (score 0):

This happens because FindWindow actually sends messages on its own that also wind up in your hook. Specifically, it sends a WM_GETTEXT to get the window's title.

To avoid that, do the FindWindow up front (outside the hook's callback).